# What exactly is Vue's runtime-only build and how does it differ from compiler build?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting this warning:

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
> template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
> into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

with my basic boilerplate code below.  I understand it's blocking me from creating my `Foo` component like that but  exactly does that mean and how does it different from another way of instantiating the Vue instance?

```js
const Foo = {
  template: `<div>xxx</div>`
}
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/', component: App}
]
    
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes:routes
})
Vue.config.productionTip = false
    
new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Full build (i.e. "compiler-included")

Also known as the "full" build, "compiler-included" includes both compiler and runtime.  The compiler is what allows using `template` strings like:

```html
template: `<div>xxx</div>`
```

**CDN**: When using Vue through a CDN, e.g. `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>`, it's typically the Full build (unless you specify otherwise).

#### Runtime-only

The alternative to template strings is the [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).  If you used only these, you wouldn't need the compiler, and could use a runtime-only build:

```js
render(h) {
  return h('div', 'xxx')
}
```

**Bundlers (e.g. Vue CLI)**: When you use a bundler like Vue CLI, it pre-builds your templates into render functions for you so that the compiler isn't needed in production.  This allows for a runtime-only build.

The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds) describe the runtime like this:

> **Runtime**: code that is responsible for creating Vue instances, rendering and patching virtual DOM, etc. Basically everything minus the compiler.

---

So, the difference between the Full build and the Runtime-only build is the inclusion or exclusion of this template compiler.

The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) explain it this way:

> If you need to compile templates on the client (e.g. passing a string to the template option, or mounting to an element using its in-DOM HTML as the template), you will need the compiler and thus the full build:

And there is this caveat to be aware of:

> Since the runtime-only builds are roughly 30% lighter-weight than their full-build counterparts you should use it whenever you can

Also in the docs are configurations for using the full build with bundlers.  In Webpack, for example, it's:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: couldn't have asked for a better explanation, thanks

Comment: That is from the Vue 2 docs. The corresponding section of the Vue 3 docs does not mention the size difference. Does that mean the size difference is not worth mentioning for Vue 3 or just that they didn't happen to mention it there. See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#runtime-compiler-vs-runtime-only

Comment: @SteveJorgensen - Not sure why they don't mention it there, it's still applicable.  In fact when comparing the Vue 3 global versions, the full build is ~50% larger  (156kb vs. 108kb)

Comment: "If you need to compile templates on the client (e.g. passing a string to the template option" you mean javascript could dynamically create another js snippet(eg: render function) and run it in browser?

Comment: @Archsx Yes, the compiler parses the string and outputs a JavaScript function.  That function creates HTML during render, using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and other HTML editing methods

Comment: In Vue 3, the compile isn't included by default for `module` import scenarios: https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/vue#with-a-bundler

Comment: @BrendonMuir - That's not always the case, it depends which dist you use.  See `vue(.runtime).esm-browser(.prod).js` section at your link under "From CDN or without a Bundler"

Comment: Sorry @Dan, I had my mind set on the node package which has the compiler excluded for a `module` import.