# Vue markraw not rendering after migrating to Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, migration, vite

After migrating to Vite from VUE CLI, all markraw components are no longer rendered.

**Example** :

```
let actions = [
{
    type: 'vue',
    component: markRaw(
    {
        template: '<router-link to="/group/' +
            Object.values(deed.deeds)[0].groupId +
            '/folder/' +
            deed.id +
            '">' +
            this.$t('show') +
            '</router-link>',
    }),
}, ];
```

On vue cli the component was rendered correctly and worked.

```
Vue : 3.0.11
Vite : 4
@vitejs/plugin-vue: 4
```

Comment: It's unknown what's a possible cause of the problem and why you think that markRaw is relevant. It's unclear what its role here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Generally there's no need for such dynamic components with string template, they won't work when vue version with no runtime compiler is used, could be the case here

Comment: when I use the vite command (development mode), the components are getting rendered properly. However, if I build first and then use vite preview in serve mode, the components aren't getting rendered.

Comment: Needs to be checked. I'd expect that these are template strings to blame. There's no real need for them nearly always, can be replaced with more idiomatic vue code any way, e.g. render functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393740/what-exactly-is-vues-runtime-only-build-and-how-does-it-differ-from-compiler-bu